How do I upgrade Unity project to new minor editor release? (2022.3.17f1 to 2022.3.45f1)
I want to migrate / move a project from 2022.3.17f1 to 2022.3.45f1. How do I do that?
Do you copy all files to new project? Do you open project with new editor?
I don't know how I should do that. Any answer is appreciated!
‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎

Just select the new version of the editor using the "Editor Version" dropdown for your project in Unity Hub, and then open it.
Once your project starts loading up, there will be a popup notifying you that the project is old, and it'll prompt you to make sure you really want to update.
If you want to be extra safe, back up your project, either through version control or by just making a copy of the folder. Nothing should break for updating between minor releases, but you never know.

Thanks for the fast answer! I will mark this answer as accepted as soon as I get to test this!

This worked! I never noticed that you can click on this! The build time is much longer in the new version, but I guess this will be so only the first time.

It should be slower for just the first time, since Unity has to redownload new versions of internal packages.
